# Changing symfony2 the routes on the fly

Tags: symfony, routes

So i need some way of changing a route like this:

/en/route/to/action

to something like this:

/route/to/action

and, at the same time, setting the "en" as the current locale.

Can i use the "routing.loader" dic tac for this? Or is there another way?

Comment: why not just use a separate route?

Comment: Because we want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle with scenario 2 : http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration#scenario-prefixing-all-routes-with-the-locale-except-those-of-the-default-locale